# Does Gladius work with the XBox360?

Tags: xbox-360, gladius

Gladius is one of those great turn-based strategy games that I like to go back to once in a while.  But now that my old PS2 is packed away, it's not so easy.  If I pick up a copy for the original XBox, will it work in my 360?

Comment: I searched and couldn't find more info than "No" without any source, so unless someone tried it and can answer, I don't know if there's an official answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [official website](http://www.xbox.com/en-GB/games/backwardcompatibilitygameslist.htm), unfortunately it isn't compatible with the XBox 360 yet. It is uncertain whether and when it ever will be.

Comment: Ah, that was the source I was missing

Comment: Since the last time that list was updated was apparently November 2007, I'm guessing they're not bothering to work on compatibility any more to add any more games to it.  Sad.

Comment: I believe Microsoft said several years ago they were done updating the Xbox emulator on the Xbox 360. If it wasn't on the last list, it wasn't ever going to make it.

Answer (score 5):

I recently bought Gladius thinking I could play it on the 360, but it says no and that there could be an update that would allow this, but I checked and there isn't. So unfortunately you can't play Gladius on the 360.

Answer (score 0):

You can't play Gladius on your Xbox 360 unless Microsoft decides to release a remake for Xbox 360.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arquade! Please refrain from repeating something already posted without reason.